# Understanding the energy transffered/used from a power source?

Tags: energy-conservation, power

A source of power(from a generator,battery,etc...) is used to power a system of any kind. We can calculate the energy used via this formula $E$ = $IV$ x $t$ ?

For example, a battery that is connected to a conductor, that conductor converts electrical energy to heat.

$E_B$ = $P$ x $t$

E - energy used from the batter.
t - time the battery is connected to the circuit and current flows.

Is this the only way to model or analyze the energy transferred?

Comment: If the power is not constant: $E=\int P dt$.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $ E = QV $.

This could be helpful if current was changing with time, but you know the amount of charge $Q$ transferred.

For example, in an electroplating or electrolysis application, you may be able to weigh the amount of product (metal plated or gas generated) and determine $Q$ directly without knowing $I$ as a function of time.